# Unable to access Cloud Endpoints on GCP Endpoints Portal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I created the `API` using `GKE` and `Cloud Endpoint gRPC` everything is fine but when I try to access my `API` from **Endpoints Portal** this is not working.

[EndPoint Portal For API](https://endpointsportal.utopian-button-227405.cloud.goog/docs/quran.endpoints.utopian-button-227405.cloud.goog/g/routes/v1/image/ayah/%7Bid%7D/get)

Enter any `id` in `ayah_id` and try to execute you will see error.

> ENOTFOUND: Error resolving domain "https://quran.endpoints.utopian-button-227405.cloud.goog"

I don't know why this is not working even my `API` is running successfully on http://34.71.56.199/v1/image/ayah/ayah-1 I'm using Http Transcoding actual `gRPC` running on `34.71.56.199:81`

I think I missed some configuration steps. Can someone please let me know what I miss.

**Update**

*api_config.yaml*

```
# The configuration schema is defined by service.proto file
# https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/service.proto
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

name: quran.endpoints.utopian-button-227405.cloud.goog

usage:
  rules:
  # Allow unregistered calls for all methods.
  - selector: "*"
    allow_unregistered_calls: true

#
# API title to appear in the user interface (Google Cloud Console).
#
title: Quran gRPC API
apis:
- name: quran.Audio
- name: quran.Ayah
- name: quran.Edition
- name: quran.Image
- name: quran.Surah
- name: quran.Translation
```

**Update 2**

*api_config.yaml*

```
# The configuration schema is defined by service.proto file
# https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/service.proto
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

name: quran.endpoints.utopian-button-227405.cloud.goog

endpoints:
- name: quran.endpoints.utopian-button-227405.cloud.goog
  target: "34.71.56.199"

usage:
  rules:
  # Allow unregistered calls for all methods.
  - selector: "*"
    allow_unregistered_calls: true

#
# API title to appear in the user interface (Google Cloud Console).
#
title: Quran gRPC API
apis:
- name: quran.Audio
- name: quran.Ayah
- name: quran.Edition
- name: quran.Image
- name: quran.Surah
- name: quran.Translation
```

*api_config_http.yaml*

```
# The configuration schema is defined by service.proto file
# https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/service.proto
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

name: quran.endpoints.utopian-button-227405.cloud.goog

#
# Http Transcoding.
#
# HTTP rules define translation from HTTP/REST/JSON to gRPC. With these rules
# HTTP/REST/JSON clients will be able to call the Quran service.
#

http:
  rules:

  #
  # Image Service transcoding
  #
  - selector: quran.Image.CreateImage
    post: '/v1/image'
    body: '*'

  - selector: quran.Image.FindImageByAyahId
    get: '/v1/image/ayah/{id}'
```

Comment: The link you posted is not public. You should instead clearly list the minimum amount of steps required to reproduce the error: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you share your api spec .yaml file? At least a minimal example with dummy data?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere what kind of dummy data

Comment: Did you follow the [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/dev-portal-explore-api#prerequisites)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry I forget to add `step 4` after adding it in my `service` file which is `api_config.yaml` in my case Now I got `internal server error 500` If you try to access it directly from `IP` address it works fine

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry I forget to add `step 4` after adding it in my `service` file which is `api_config.yaml` in my case Now I got `internal server error 500` If you try to access it directly from `IP` address it works fine